# Cakephp ACL for User HABTM Role

Tags: cakephp

I have a HABTM relationship between User and Role. How do I implement ACL in Cakephp in this situation and is it possible at all?

Comment: what exactly you interested in? ACL used to abtract permissions from Roles, so, it's not important which relationship between User and Role

Comment: I am using the ACL component from Cakephp and from what I read it only supports a one to one relationship between User and Role. Is there any way to use HABTM between the 2 entities?

Comment: Seems, I did not understand your question. Can you demonstrate your code? or some errors which you have. In general, you need to: create aro, aco, and permissions, after that implement parentNode method in models, add ACL behaviour for User model and other if needed and it should work. Also, try to check this tutorials: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-use-cakephps-access-control-lists/
http://mark-story.com/posts/view/auth-and-acl-an-end-to-end-tutorial-pt-1
http://mark-story.com/posts/view/auth-and-acl-an-end-to-end-tutorial-pt-2

Comment: My user has many roles. I see in the cake book that the ACL examples are only based on a User having one role. Can I implement User has many roles with using the ACL component? I hope thats clearer. If not I will post some code examples